# Change a String

Tags: jquery, string, variables, selector

Not sure how to ask this question, but here goes.

Say I have:

```
var foo = 'marginLeft';
```

How can I change it into:

```
marginLeft
```

So this would be possible:

```
$(element).animate({foo: 20});
```

Please note, not looking for this (I want the curly braces):

```
$(element).animate(foo,20);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you should be able to get the same behavior with something like this:

```
var foo = "marginLeft";
var x = {};
x[foo]=20;

$(element).animate(x);
```

Comment: How do I add a duration to that? `$(element).animate(x, 1000);` ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You can't use a variable as a object key. This is the limitation of the literal object syntax of javascript.